# Creating a BMP file (bitmap) in C

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

I'm trying to make a bitmap in C, just from code. I'm currently trying to make a very easy .bmp image, with a height of 1px and a width of 4 pixels, with all white pixels. I have read the format description and tried to apply it. This resulted in the following code:

```
char bitmap[1000];

void BMPmake()
{
    // -- FILE HEADER -- //

    // bitmap signature
    bitmap[0] = 'B';
    bitmap[1] = 'M';

    // file size
    bitmap[2] = 66; // 40 + 14 + 12
    bitmap[3] = 0;
    bitmap[4] = 0;
    bitmap[5] = 0;

    // reserved field (in hex. 00 00 00 00)
    for(int i = 6; i < 10; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // offset of pixel data inside the image
    for(int i = 10; i < 14; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // -- BITMAP HEADER -- //

    // header size
    bitmap[14] = 40;
    for(int i = 15; i < 18; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // width of the image
    bitmap[18] = 4;
    for(int i = 19; i < 22; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // height of the image
    bitmap[22] = 1;
    for(int i = 23; i < 26; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // reserved field
    bitmap[26] = 1;
    bitmap[27] = 0;

    // number of bits per pixel
    bitmap[28] = 24; // 3 byte
    bitmap[29] = 0;

    // compression method (no compression here)
    for(int i = 30; i < 34; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // size of pixel data
    bitmap[34] = 12; // 12 bits => 4 pixels
    bitmap[35] = 0;
    bitmap[36] = 0;
    bitmap[37] = 0;

    // horizontal resolution of the image - pixels per meter (2835)
    bitmap[38] = 0;
    bitmap[39] = 0;
    bitmap[40] = 0b00110000;
    bitmap[41] = 0b10110001;

    // vertical resolution of the image - pixels per meter (2835)
    bitmap[42] = 0;
    bitmap[43] = 0;
    bitmap[44] = 0b00110000;
    bitmap[45] = 0b10110001;

    // color pallette information
    for(int i = 46; i < 50; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // number of important colors
    for(int i = 50; i < 54; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // -- PIXEL DATA -- //
    for(int i = 54; i < 66; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;
}

void BMPwrite()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("bitmap.bmp", "w+");
    for(int i = 0; i < 66; i++)
    {
        fputc(bitmap[i], file);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

When I try to open this image, it says that the image is damaged. Am I missing something here?

I also noticed that the encoding of the .bmp integers is little endian. I thought that this mean that I have to reverse the order of the bytes. For example, 256 in four bytes is: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000, and I think in little endian this would be: 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000

Can anyone give me a hand here? Am I using a right approach? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Draw an image that you would like to generate using your favorite graphic editor, and then try replicating it byte-for-byte.

Comment: You've got the endianness wrong on the resolution fields. You will find your work much easier if you write helper functions to take 2-byte and 4-byte integers and pack them into your byte array for you.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, I've tried doing that in Pixelmator (on Mac), but I got a bmp file of 84 bytes while I'm expecting it to be 66 bytes, maybe I can try opening it with a program that shows me byte per byte ;)

Comment: Note that using binary literals (prefixed with `0b`) is a compiler extension, it's not part of C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your pixel offset (bytes 10..13) is zero, but the pixel data don't actually start at the beginning of the file, they start at byte 54.

Also:

- Your comment on byte 34 says "bits" but means "bytes", but of course that doesn't matter.
- Your horizontal and vertical resolutions have the wrong byte order, but I very much doubt that that matters.

If I were doing this I'd define structs for the header data (indeed, if you're on Windows, Microsoft have already done this) and use a macro or something for putting bytes into the right order portably.

Whether you "have to reverse the order of the bytes" depends on the endianity of the processor you're using. Writing separate bytes separately, as you're doing, is an effective way to avoid having to worry about this.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that the offset is the number of bytes between the beginning of the file and the beginning of the pixel data? So in this case it would be 54 bytes (14 bytes for the file header and 40 for the bitmap header)?

Comment: I've got it working now! The problem was indeed with the pixel offset, I've changed it to 54 and now I can open the bitmap! Thanks everyone for their help :)

Comment: Correct. [Ignore this note -- it's just some extra text because Stack Overflow doesn't allow very short comments.]

Comment: (Oops, didn't see your comment before adding that. What actually happened is that I just typed "Correct.", hit "Add Comment", and went away to do something else important -- then came back an hour later and found it hadn't posted.)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code tested on linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define _height 600
#define _width 800
#define _bitsperpixel 24
#define _planes 1
#define _compression 0
#define _pixelbytesize _height*_width*_bitsperpixel/8
#define _filesize _pixelbytesize+sizeof(bitmap)
#define _xpixelpermeter 0x130B //2835 , 72 DPI
#define _ypixelpermeter 0x130B //2835 , 72 DPI
#define pixel 0xFF
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct{
    uint8_t signature[2];
    uint32_t filesize;
    uint32_t reserved;
    uint32_t fileoffset_to_pixelarray;
} fileheader;
typedef struct{
    uint32_t dibheadersize;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitsperpixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imagesize;
    uint32_t ypixelpermeter;
    uint32_t xpixelpermeter;
    uint32_t numcolorspallette;
    uint32_t mostimpcolor;
} bitmapinfoheader;
typedef struct {
    fileheader fileheader;
    bitmapinfoheader bitmapinfoheader;
} bitmap;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main (int argc , char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.bmp","wb");
    bitmap *pbitmap  = (bitmap*)calloc(1,sizeof(bitmap));
    uint8_t *pixelbuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(_pixelbytesize);
    strcpy(pbitmap->fileheader.signature,"BM");
    pbitmap->fileheader.filesize = _filesize;
    pbitmap->fileheader.fileoffset_to_pixelarray = sizeof(bitmap);
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.dibheadersize =sizeof(bitmapinfoheader);
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.width = _width;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.height = _height;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.planes = _planes;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.bitsperpixel = _bitsperpixel;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.compression = _compression;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.imagesize = _pixelbytesize;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.ypixelpermeter = _ypixelpermeter ;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.xpixelpermeter = _xpixelpermeter ;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.numcolorspallette = 0;
    fwrite (pbitmap, 1, sizeof(bitmap),fp);
    memset(pixelbuffer,pixel,_pixelbytesize);
    fwrite(pixelbuffer,1,_pixelbytesize,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    free(pbitmap);
    free(pixelbuffer);
}
```

Comment: This assumes your native endianness is the same as Windows' (the originator of the BMP file format). "Tested on linux" tells nothing about possible endianness issues.

Answer (score 3):

Open your file with a hex editor to see what is actually there.  This will help you determine if your code is doing something unexpected.

Comment: Definitely going to try that tomorrow! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: BTW, you might want to open the file in "wb+" (binary) mode.